# After moving to a new domain, should I remove the properties for the old domain from Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, domains, site-verification

We currently have two properties in our Search Console account:

- `https://www.NewURL.tld` (this is our canonical URL)
- `https://www.OldURL.tld` (now redirects to `www.NewURL.tld`)

We just went through a company name change and re-branding.

I understand I need to add three more properties:

- `https://NewURL.tld`
- `http://www.NewURL.tld`
- `http://NewURL.tld`

Should I remove the `https://www.OldURL.tld` from the properties list? 
I am assuming so, but wanted to get your opinions as well.

Comment: I would add 4 properties https ://www. NewURL.tld too.

Answer (score 3):

As a good practice, you should always keep old, new and all variations of both as a property on Google Search Console. But why? this is due to the fact that should a problem arise Google can notify you. This includes but not limited by redirect hacks, malware and even penalties.